# Combine WSO2 ESB with WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-esb

I'm considering using the functions of WSO2 IS. However, I already have WSO2 ESB deployed in a production environment, so I'd prefer to add IS features to the already existent ESB environment.

I was able to start with the IS 4.1.0 bundle, add the [Carbon 4.0.5 P2 repository](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.5/) (ESB 4.6.0 is built upon that version of Carbon) and install ESB 4.6.0 features, but I cannot seem to be able to do the opposite, since as far as I can tell WSO2 IS is based on Carbon 4.0.6, but [there's no P2 repo for it](http://wso2.org/projects/carbon/provisioning-wso2-carbon-with-equinox-p2).

What's the proper way to install IS features into ESB, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried installing 4.0.7 Identity Server features to ESB 4.0.6. But I can advice you to not to do it. Reason is: Identity Server 4.1.0 has some changes done to the user management core bundles which are not compatible with the older releases. Therefore, you can try to install an older version of identity server features on top of ESB 4.6.0. Identity Server 4.0.0 was released with Carbon 4.0.3. So, I think you should try with [Carbon 4.0.3 p2 repository](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.3/) to install identity features on ESB 4.6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I managed to install it that way, but from a cursory glance, OAuth support seems to be missing, I can't find it in the feature list anywhere. Also, all pages under Main > Entitlement fail to render and blow up with a ServletException, so perhaps they're not compatible...

Comment: Ah, it was because ESB comes with org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub_4.0.0.jar, which conflicts with the one IS pulls in... I removed the 4.0.0 one and things seem to work at a first sight, but it makes me a bit uncomfortable removing jars by hand. Is there a way to check which feature pulled in that jar file?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There should be OSGi commands which can show which feature installed a given jar. I dont know those OSGi commands, but you might be able to find them in the internet. If you find them, you can start WSO2 servers with a OSGi console by passing -DosgiConsole property at startup and check.

Answer (score 0):

Please use 4.0.7 P2 repository for new IS features which IS 4.1.0 based on.

http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.7/

Comment: Thanks for replying. Oddly enough, I can't expand the "Identity Server" category when I add the 4.0.7 repository to ESB: http://puu.sh/2xsLw . The other repositories work fine. What's strange is that if I put something in "Filter by feature name", it works, but then I think I'm filtering out some components that I should be installing. Any idea how to solve that?