# How to add features of wso2 Application Server in wso2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way to install features of WSO2 Application Server in WSO2 ESB ?
I have read [Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914166/combine-wso2-esb-with-wso2-is) on StackOverflow but still I am confused regarding the workaround required ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow this [doc](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Installing+Features) to install WSO2 Application Server features in ESB. This doc is for ESB 4.7.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [official doc](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Installing+Features) as a guide. For the repository select the 'default repository'. Then select the 'Application Server' feature category and install it. Make sure to restart the ESB after installing.